# Настенные часы или стенные?

Tags: грамотная-речь

Как правильно говорить? В чём разница?

Answer (score 3):

Правильны оба варианта: **стенные часы** и **настенные часы**.

http://diclist.ru/slovar/ushakova/b/stennoj.html

http://diclist.ru/slovar/ushakova/h/nastennyj.html

Answer (score 2):

В настоящее время употребляются **оба варианта**. Если посмотреть по Нацкорпусу, то после 1950 года частотность употребления примерно одинаковая,  а вот раньше часы назывались стенными (первая запись "настенные часы" в Нацкорпусе отмечена в 1940 году).

**Семантика вроде бы похожая** (о чем говорит и статистика употребления), но некоторые различия в значении всё-таки есть. **Настенные** ― это висящие на стене, а **стенные** ― предназначенные для размещения на стене, имеющие особую конструкцию для этого, противопоставленные другим видам часов.

Остается узнать, кто первым назвал часы настенными.